# Live streaming with Azure Media Services

Tags: java, android, azure-media-services

I'm working on an Android application that allows users to live stream with Azure Media Services. Getting stuck with a problem that I can't seem to push the audio stream to the channel. Here is the ingest URL: rtp://audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:2010/ (Modified slightly) and here is my code:

```
try {
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        AudioGroup audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
        audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream((InetAddress.getByName("audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net")));
        audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioStream.associate(InetAddress.getByName("audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net"),2010);
        audioStream.join(audioGroup);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("AS",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
java.net.SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
--> AudioStream((InetAddress.getByName("audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net")));
```

Could someone please shed some light on this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net? It seems your device or emulator can't resove dns name.

Comment: @GeorgeTrifonov Hi, sorry for the late reply, that's the problem, I was given this URL in the channel rtp://audio-audio.rtp.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:2010/ but have absolutely no idea how to push an audio-only stream from the Android device to the channel.